# Luxair F2FP048N06H, 2 stage heating and single stage cooling. No PC Board

Tags: wiring, hvac

My Luxair F2FP048N06H, PC board was removed a while back, and I do not have a schematic for the way it was hard wired. Does anyone have a wiring diagram so I can wire the unit back without a circuit a board.
The sequencer burnt and when we replaced it some of the wiring came loose and I do not know how it was wired. It's a 4-ton 2 stage unit but all the elements are coming on at once now causing it to get too hot.
I need a wiring diagram for a hard-wired single stage Air and 2 stage heat unit.
Thanks

Comment: do you mean Luxair**e** F2FP048N06H

Comment: Deadly mistake, not taking pictures and not having schematic

Comment: Have you tried contacting Luxaire to ask if they have a wiring schematic that you can download?